# Which is the Inbox folder for the imap sever outlook.office365.com

Tags: c#, imap

I'm trying to get the email from an account in server outlook.office365.com using S22.Imap and I'm getting this error:

xm009 NO inbox doesn't exist.

I have tried different folder names (Inbox, INBOX)
I have listed the folders and no one seems to be the one for the inbox
also I have tried using thunderbird and claws mail and none worked correctly and I couldn't read the new email, all folders are empty
How can I read the new mail for this server?

Comment: Have a browse though the code here and see if that helps: https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap

Comment: Sounds like that account is borked.  The name of INBOX (case-insensitive) is defined by RFC3501 to be the primary folder of the account.  If it doesn’t have an INBOX, then this account is not IMAP compliant.  Perhaps it doesn’t actually have one for some reason or another.